# When running python 3.9.4 I am unable to import tkinter, but downgrading to 3.8.2 works perfectly fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8, python-3.9

Im on macOS Catalina running tcl 8.6.11, I installed python3 using
`brew install python3`

```
tclsh
% info patchlevel
8.6.11
```

Current version of python 3.9.4

```
python3 --version 
Python 3.9.4 

>>> import tkinter 
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Downgrading to 3.8.2

```
python3 --version 
Python 3.8.2

>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

Not sure what is causing this, any insight would be appreciated

Comment: are you using Linux, Windows, or MacOS

Comment: Im running macOS catalina

Comment: Was 3.8.2 also installed from brew?  Or from python.org?  Either way, talk to brew or check their docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like tkinter is disabled in brew for python 3.9 but not for 3.8, 
[it's commented on their github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/python@3.9.rb#L171).

Try the [python-tk](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python-tk@3.9#default) formula if you want to use python 3.9.